# Creating a block with two async requests and a completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to make this block.

```
+ (void)getUsersAndTracksWithSearch:(NSString *)search withCompletion:(void(^)(NSMutableArray *users, NSMutableArray *tracks)) completion
{

}
```

I am using SoundCloud API. I am using their API method for getting a list of tracks and users. which is:

```
 [SCRequest performMethod:SCRequestMethodGET
                  onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:userURL]
             usingParameters:nil
                 withAccount:nil
      sendingProgressHandler:nil
             responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
     })];
```

I am using this method twice and getting two responses, so how should I set up a block so that on completion of the block I have both responses?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NSOperationQueue, it can be used in a way which chains their operations i.e. chains their blocks.